# Accessing an enum with Enum() == access by index?

Tags: solidity

How can you compare an enum to a uint8?

```
enum Op { NONE, EQ, NEQ, GT, LT, GTE, LTE, RET, NOT, AND, OR, XOR, IF_ELSE }
struct Param {
    uint8 op;
}
```

I have a `Param param;` which has the enum's index saved as uint8 on `param.op`.
Then I have seen before a comparison like so:

`if (Op(param.op) == Op.NONE)`

However, I didn't find any documentation about accessing an enum like it's happening here: `Op(uint8variable)`

If eg. `enum Enum { BLA }` is accessed through `Enum()`, what does that do exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can see `Op(param.op)` as a *cast* from **uint8** to the enum type **Op**. Indeed Solidity supports explicit conversion from and to int types, but implicit conversion is not allowed that's why you need that.

`if (Op(param.op) == Op.NONE)` will compile, while `if (param.op == Op.NONE)` will not. Same if you try to convert a enum type to int

```
function test() public pure returns(uint8) {
    return uint8(Op.NONE); //explicit conversion allowed
    // with return Op.NONE; you will get an error at compile time 
}
```

Comment: Dear @mirg 
Thank you for your answer. I kind of understand. However, coming from a JS background, I'm not sure what "casting" means... Do you have any good links I could read up on? The solidity docs also don't mention this.

Comment: in a nutshell, casting means convert a variable from a type to another. You can find some more explanation here https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/224493/what-is-casting-supposed-to-mean and here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion

Answer (score 0):

**Enums :** 
Enums are one way to create a user-defined type in Solidity.

```
// Lets see Enums which are often used for state machine like this
enum State { Created, Locked, Inactive };

// post this a variable can be Declared like this
State public state;

// Initializing the state can be done like this
state = State.Created;

// It is important to note that enums can be explicitly converted to ints like this
uint createdState = uint(State.Locked);
```